# SSL on only one page of Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have setup SSL on a page of my wordpress site i.e. /checkout which works fine.

when you visit the home page or any other page for that matter the url in the browser reads as http://www.mydomain.com, which is good.

However when you view source of the page everything included the stylesheert is linked via https://

is there something I can use in htaccess to stop this happening?

Answer (score 0):

In your Wordpress WP-Admin settings, you will have set the URL for the website, which Wordpress will use for handling all URLs (including links to CSS, JS, etc files).

Is there any reason you can't run your entire Wordpress website on SSL? It's a much cleaner solution then jumping in and out of SSL for specific pages of your site.